# Can we have more than just debug & release configurations in Visual Studio?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, configuration-files

In a new Visual Studio ASP.NET project we get `web.debug.config` and `web.release.config` out-of-the-box.  XDT transforms allow us to manipulate the the contents of these files.  Is it possible to add more of this type of file?

Can we, for example, get a `web.custom.config` (and list it under web.config) so we can switch between debug, custom & release configurations, in the same way we currently switch between debug & release?

Comment: You need to also create a project configuration named "custom", https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/web-config-transformations#default-transformation-files then "Add Config Transforms" should work.

Comment: Thanks Lex Li - that's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you right-click the solution in Solution Explorer and access properties you will see a properties dialog that lets you select Configuration Properties. At the top right of that dialog you will see a Configuration Manager button. Click that to launch the Configuration Manager dialog. Click the Active solution configuration dropdown list and select New... to make a new configuration. See screenshot below.

[image]